# How do I deserialize a Json Object with an Array inside it

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to take in JSON that has an array in an object.

```
{"attr1":"value", "attr2":"value", "attr3": [{"chldattr1":"value", "chldattr2":"value"}], "attr4":"value"}
```

Classes have been made or deserializing it into an object.

```
namespace Contracts
{
    class Contract
    {
        public string Attr1 { get; set; }
        public string Attr2 { get; set; }
        public List<ChildElement> Attr3s { get; set; }
        public string Attr4 { get; set; }        
    }
    class ChildElement
    {
        public string ChldAttr1 { get; set; }
        public string ChldAttr2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

when I try
`List<Contract> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contract>>(jsonString)`
the error I get is

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Program.Contracts.Contract]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting this fixed.

Comment: Your json is not a List of Contract but it is a single Contract.

Comment: You `Attr3s` property name does not match the name in the json.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Contracts
{
    public class Contract
    {
        [JsonProperty("attr1")]
        public string Attr1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("attr2")]
        public string Attr2 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("attr3")]
        public List<ChildElement> Attr3s { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("attr4")]
        public string Attr4 { get; set; }        
    }
    public class ChildElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("chldattr1")]
        public string ChldAttr1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("chldattr2")]
        public string ChldAttr2 { get; set; }
    }
}

Contract contract = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contract>(jsonString);
```

You need to make sure the properties names of the class match that of the json properties. Use `[JsonProperty("name")]` attribute to fix that.

Your Json is a single object.. you cannot deserialize it to a List.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the deserializing to a list as I was copying and pasting when I made that line.

Comment: @RadialWaves if this answers your question, i would suggest clicking the ✔ under the votes to mark this answered

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer doesn't recognize attr3 is the same as Attr3s.
Either change Attr3s to be Attr3, or specify the jsonproperty name with [JsonProperty("name")]